# The right way to write masonry code? in “- init” or “- layoutSubViews”

Tags: ios, snapkit, masonry-ios-osx

Both ways seem to work, are there any differences in performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it really depends on what you want to do. You can call it from `init` but then the code will only be called when you instantiate the class. If you put it in `layoutSubviews` you can have the code called multiple times by making the view redraw.

So if you need to update constraints based on things changing it could be advantageous to use `layoutSubviews` but if you don't need to modify the constraints I would personally make a new method called `setConstraints` which would contain all the constraints and call that from `init`